# Пинг Понг, не могу понять как игроками(потоками) проверить удар по мячу и где сделать синхронизацию

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

работа в windows form.
Игра в пинг-понг
А. Программа игры двух потоков в пинг-понг. Потоки управляют ракетками – бьют по очереди по мячу.
Сделать вариант программы в форме, с графикой, с управлением ракетками клавишами, счетом.

смог реализовать все без потоков, а вот с ними не могу, нужно запилить синхронизацию с потоками.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        Player [] player;
        Thread [] potok;
        int FPS = 60;
        Graphics graphics;

        int ballx;
        int bally;
        int ballspdx = 5;
        int ballspdy = 5;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            graphics = CreateGraphics();
            ballx = Width / 2;
            bally = Height / 2;
            potok = new Thread[2];
            player = new  Player[2];
            player[0] = new Player(0,this.Height / 3);
            player[1] = new Player(Width - 35, this.Height / 3);
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Interval = 1000 / FPS;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerCallback);


            Start();



        }

        void Start() 
        {
            for (int i = 0;i < player.Length;i++) 
            {
                potok[i] = new Thread(player[0].Play);
                potok[i].Start();
            }
        }

        void UpdateBall()
        {
            ballx += ballspdx;
            bally += ballspdy;



            if (bally < 0 || bally + 40 > this.Height)
            {
                ballspdy = -ballspdy;
            }

            if (IsCollided())
            {
                ballspdx = -ballspdx;
            }

            if (ballx < 0 || ballx > this.Width - 40)
            {
                
                label1.Show();
                label1.Text = "GAME OVER";
                timer.Stop();
            }
        }

           public  bool IsCollided()
        {
            if (ballx < 20 && bally > player[0].y && bally < player[0].y + 130 || ballx > this.Width - 50 && bally > player[1].y && bally < player[1].y + 130)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        void TimerCallback(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            UpdateBall();
            this.Invalidate();
           return;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Rectangle(ballx, bally, 20, 20));
            graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow),new Rectangle(Width/2,0,10,Height));
            player[0].DrawPlayer(e.Graphics,new SolidBrush(Color.Black));
            player[1].DrawPlayer(e.Graphics, new SolidBrush(Color.Red));
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            int key = e.KeyValue;
            if (key == 87) { player[0].y -= 7; }
            if (key == 83) { player[0].y += 7; }
            if (key == 38) { player[1].y -= 7; }
            if (key == 40) { player[1].y += 7; }

        }

        private void Form1_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < player.Length; i++)
            {
                player[i].live = false;
            }
        }

        
    }

 class Player
    {
        public bool live = true;
        public int x;
        public int y;

        
        public Player(int x,int y)
        {
            
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void DrawPlayer(Graphics graphics, SolidBrush Color) 
        {
            graphics.FillRectangle(Color, new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 130));
        }
        public void  Play() 
        {
        }
    }
```

думал в методе Play()(он и запускается в потоке) сделать вызов метода IsCollided() сделать в нём синхронизацию, но как из потока  вызвать его, и пока один поток не ударит по мячу другой поток ждет, и так по кругу.

не обязательно такая реализация, может нужно выделить больше классов,и как-то отталкиваться от этого.

Comment: `Программа игры двух потоков в пинг-понг.` Это прямо в задании так написано или это Вы своими словами излагаете? Программа должна играть сама с собой? Или человек должен играть с компьютером? Или два человека друг с другом?

Comment: два человека друг с другом